# Regular Expression for keeping number between brackets and getting rid of all else SEE EXAMPLE?

Tags: regex, replace, find, emeditor

Sorry I imagine this is a trivial one but I'm a rookie with regular expressions.

I want to replace every entry of number long in a document E.G

> NumberLong(1000)

with

> "1000"

using find and replace. IE keep the number and put quotations around it delete number long and brackets.

Could anyone tell me how this is done?

Answer (score 1):

well this can help you to test your regular expresion based on lagunage

https://regexr.com/

Comment: Thank's I'm a bit clueless with where to start though